# Spring - An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling". org/eclipse/jdt/core/search/SearchPattern

Tags: java, spring

I'm having trouble opening Java files because of this error. 
Everything runs perfectly when I start the server...

[image: error screen capture]

This isn't the first time I'm having initializing java tooling error, so of course, I deleted the folders suggested and switching workspace from other posts I've seen.

I don't know why I'm keep having this error... Any help or comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-downloaded new spring sts and unzipped the files included.

It seems some of the files have not been unzipped properly on the first attempt  :/

(I'm still getting this error, but at least the Spring Tool Suite (sts) is reading the java files properly now ...)